# How to add a new method called numberOfDigits() in java?

Tags: java, methods

I have a program called public class ZeroCounter {. I want to add a new method to it called  numberOfDigits() and add a line to test it in the main() method. How should I go about doing it?  Below is a small part of the code.

```
public class ZeroCounter   {
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("Enter a nonnegative number:");
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         int number = keyboard.nextInt( ) ;

         System.out.println(number + " contains " + numberOfZeros(number) + " zeros.");
} // End of main
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class ZeroCounter   {
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("Enter a nonnegative number:");
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         int number = keyboard.nextInt( ) ;

         System.out.println(number + " contains " + numberOfZeros(number) + " zeros.");
         int theDigit = keyboard.nextInt( ) ;    //added for the digitcount
         int digitCount = numberOfDigits(number, theDigit); 

    }// End of main

// * * * * Recursive Method * * * * 
public static int numberOfZeros(int n)  {
n = Math.abs(n); // Make sure the number is not negative. 

// 1. STOPPING CONDITION: Number has only only digit. 
if ( n < 10 )  {
    // if( n == 0 ) return 1;   else return 0;

    return n==0 ? 1:  0 ; // Conditional  operator.

} // end of the outer if block handling the stopping condition.


// 2. Else handle the case of two or more digits using recursion.
else {

    return n%10 == 0 ? 1 + numberOfZeros(n/10):  numberOfZeros(n/10) ; // Conditional  operator.


    // if (n%10 == 0) return 1 + numberOfZeros(n/10);
    // else return numberOfZeros(n/10);
} // end of outer else block 


} // end of recursive method method numberOfZeros. * * * * * * * * 


public static int numberOfDigits(int n, int digit) {
n = Math.abs(n); // Make sure the number is not negative.  
if ( n < 10 )  { 
     if( n == digit )    return 1;  
else           return 0; 
} // end of the outer if block handling the stopping condition. 
// 2. Else handle the case of two or more digits using recursion. 
else {   
      if (n%10 == digit) return 1 + numberOfDigits(n/10, digit);
        else return numberOfDigits(n/10, digit); 
} // end of outer else block 
} // end of recursive method method numberOfZeros. * * * * * * * *  
}
```

Comment: start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: How did you add a function called main() in the first place? The process will be pretty much the same, but the function will be called numberOfDigits() instead of main().

Comment: Your method must be static if you want to use it in the main.

Comment: To get the digit count in a number, translate it to a string, and then get its length.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ZeroCounter   {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Enter a nonnegative number:");
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         int number = keyboard.nextInt( ) ;

         System.out.println(number + " contains " + numberOfZeros(number) + " zeros.");
  } // End of main

  private static int numberOfZeros(int number) {
         int result = ///// calculation
         return result;
  }
}
```

You might want to read up a bit more on Java and how classes, methods and functions work first before going any further however.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to count digits of  an integer number:-

```
 public int numberOfZeros(int number){
    return ((int) Math.log10(number) + 1);
}
```

Or you can try this code

```
      //Declare input as scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Take input
         System.out.println("Enter Number :");
         no = input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter digit :");
         digit = input.nextInt();

        //add while loop
        while(no>0)
        {
            m=no%10;
            if(m==digit)
                oc++;
            no=no/10;
        }

        System.out.println("Digit occurred "+oc+" times");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public class ZeroCounter {

    public static int numberOfDigits(int number) {
        //- Implementation goes here.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        //- Initialize number variable.
        System.out.println("numberOfDigits(" + number + ")=" + numberOfDigits(number));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! If I already have a                                         public static int numberOfZeros(int n)  {
n = Math.abs(n); 

// 1. STOPPING CONDITION: Number has only only digit. 
if ( n < 10 )  {
 // if( n == 0 ) return 1; else return 0;
Can I still add another public static int numberOfDigits(int number) {  ?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many (almost) new methods as you want. Some of them can even have exactly the same names as only they differ as to the arguments (their types and/or count) --- this is called "method overloading". For instance you can have one public static int numberOfDigits(int number) that takes int as a parameter and another one public static int numberOfDigits(String number) that takes string and counts digits in it (possibly skipping other characters like letters, brackets, etc).

Comment: ok so I added this part to my code 
    public static int numberOfDigits(int number)  {
    System.out.println("Enter a nonnegative integer:"); 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    int number = keyboard.nextInt( ) ; 
    System.out.println("Specify the digit you would like to count."
     + " \nEnter a digit from 0 - 9 ");
But its all highlighted in red. would you happen to know why?

Comment: It looks like it misses return statement. Look at the "int" right after "public static". It tells, that method numberOfDigits must *return* a value of type int. Adding "return number" at the end of method body would do the trick. Although this method would not do, what I guess, you really wanted it to do...

Comment: You rather should use your methods (like numberOfDigits numberOfZeros) as simple code, that does only what the method's name say --- count number of digits or zeros. All the code involved with reading input from user should be placed somewhere else (eg. in main method).

Comment: So i added this towards the end, but still it seems like there is a problem. 
public static int numberOfDigits(int n, int digit) {
n = Math.abs(n); // Make sure the number is not negative.  
if ( n < 10 )  { 
     if( n == digit )    return 1;  
else           return 0; 
} 
// 2. Else handle the case of two or more digits using recursion. 
else {  
      if (n%10 == digit) return 1 + numberOfDigits(n/10, digit);
   else return numberOfDigits(n/10, digit); 
} // 
} // 
}

Comment: Getting that box, that says "One or more projects were complied with errors" . If you look above, in the question, i have posted my updated code!

Comment: Updated code compiles, so it must be coming from something else. Also possibly, that some warnings are treated as errors... Please look carefully for some more error messages (I believe there must be some kind of panel with detailed messages --- nowadays every IDE has it).

Comment: Syntax is OK however, formatting looks terrible. ;-) But I don't actually know, what the code should do... I mean, even if it compiles, it doesn't mean that it does not have errors. Looking at what it does, it's not what I would expected it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... :)

```
public class ZeroCounter {

    public static int numberOfDigits(int number) 
    {
        //return Integer.toString(number).length();
        return String.valueOf(number).length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number;
        Scanner Keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
        number=Keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("numberOfDigits(" + number + ")=" + numberOfDigits(number));
    }
}
```

**Updated Code..**

```
import java.util.*;
public class ZeroCounter 
{

public static int numberOfDigits(int number,char d) 
{           
    //to get a char array of digits of number
    char[] n=Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();
    int r=0;
    for(char x:n)
    {
        if(x==d)
            r++;
    }
    return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number;
    char digit;
    boolean flag=false;
    Scanner Keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
    System.out.print("Enter the non-negative number: ");
    number=Keyboard.nextInt();

    //to check number is positive or not
    if(number<=-1)
    throw new Exception();
    System.out.println(number + " contains " + numberOfDigits(number,'0') + " zeros.");
    System.out.print("Enter the digit: ");

    //to take only one letter as input
    digit=Keyboard.next(".").charAt(0);

    //to check input is digit or not
    if(!Character.isDigit(digit))
    throw new Exception();
    System.out.println("Number of digits(" + digit + ")=" + numberOfDigits(number,digit));
    }
       //to catch all exceptions
    catch(Exception e)
    {  
        System.out.println("\n You have entered invalid input..");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks!  this is what I got for so far, but it doesn't look right (please look a the updated qs i posted)

Comment: System.out.println("numberOfDigits(" + number + ")=" + numberOfDigits(number)); is highlighted in red. error is "method numberofDigits in class ZeroCounter cannot be applied to given types; required : int,int. Found int"